# ploblem using csv in python3

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
with open('c:/python34/test.csv', 'a', encoding='cp949') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['num']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n',)
     writer.writeheader()
     writer.writerow({'num': '04'})
```

result when I open test.csv file

> 4

I want write **`04`** in csv file , but it is **`4`** when I open test.csv file
help me

Comment: Your code is setting `04` in the file for me

Comment: What are you opening the file with? if it's excel it strips leading zeros. You might want to add 04 in in quotes to ensure it keeps the 0

Comment: @JanR i want  04 in excel file... but  in result is 4...

Comment: Add an extra ' in front of the 04, that should allow leading 0s in excel

Comment: i opened in excel file

Comment: @JanR i dont understand explain me easly please

Answer (score 0):

try this to add an extra ' in front of the 04 to allow it to not be stripped in excel:

```
import csv
with open('c:/python34/test.csv', 'a', encoding='cp949') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['num']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n',)
     writer.writeheader()
     writer.writerow({'num': '\'04'}) #changed to escaped '
```

Comment: i write '\'04'  but in result  '04    why have '    i  want only 04 not '04

Comment: excel should ignore the ' and display it as string

Comment: but yes in your csv it will display as '04

Comment: it's a way to trick excel into thinking it's dealing with text rather than a number, as excel will ALWAYS strip leading 0s on numbers

Comment: i can see only ' no number in excel ,when i write  writer.writerow({'num': "'04"})

Comment: ok that must be my lacking python skills, changed it back to the escaped '